# Thread with Lambda expression

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, interrupted-exception

I have an error at line 42 and 43 : `Thread t1=new Thread(()->prod.test());` , `Thread t2=new Thread(()->cons.test());` *Unhandled exception type InterruptedException* . If I try to quickfix it will created the try catch with an catch *Exception*, it will have the same error and will try to fix it in the same way continuing to surround it with try catch.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

interface Predicate {
    public void test() throws InterruptedException;
}

class MyClass {
    int num = 0;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            num++;
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            num--;
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

}

public class Main00 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        Predicate prod = c::produce;
        Predicate cons = c::consume;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> prod.test());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> cons.test());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time taken " + (end - start) + " num = "
                + c.getNum());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have created a functional interface `Predicate` whose method is declared to throw an `InterruptedException`, which is a checked exception.  However, you call `test()` in the body of a lambda expression as the parameter to [the `Thread` constructor that takes a `Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-), whose [`run()` method is not declared to throw any checked exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--).  Therefore, because the exception is not caught in the body, a compiler error occurs.

Incidentally, it may be confusing to name your own interface `Predicate`, because of the [built-in functional interface `java.util.function.Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) whose functional method returns a `boolean`.

Because `run()` can't throw an `Exception`, you must `catch` the exception and handle it.  You might log the exception and its stack trace.  You might wrap the exception in a `RuntimeException`.  Either way, catching the checked exception will allow the code to compile.  Example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        prod.test();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle: log or throw in a wrapped RuntimeException
        throw new RuntimeException("InterruptedException caught in lambda", e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exception 'java.lang.InterruptedException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block.

Comment: @ShadowGames This particular definition of `Predicate` declares `test` to throw `InterruptedException`, so it can be thrown and it must be caught.

Answer (score 10):

If you intend on running a single method only with no arguments you can replace the lambda with a method reference.

For instance:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        foo();
    });
```

can be more succinctly expressed as

```
Thread t = new Thread(this::foo);
```

To start it

```
t.start();
```

Comment: I'm assuming you still need to call `t.start()` (which isn't relevant to the question, but until I get my head around lambdas it's better I ask!).

Answer (score 3):

As @rgettman says, the name `Predicate` is unhappy... Anyways, you could take advantage of `default` methods in Java:

```
interface PredicateButPleaseChangeMyName {

    void test() throws InterruptedException;

    default void tryTest() {
       try {
          this.test();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // handle e (log or wrap in a RuntimeException)
       }
    }
}
```

Then, in your main method, simply create the threads by calling the default `tryTest()` method:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> prod.tryTest());
Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> cons.tryTest());
```