# How am I able to access non-final variable from anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, oop, final, anonymous-inner-class

I have 2 Java classes.

1. TestLogging
2. Test2

In both the classes I have written the same logic. But in TestLogging class, I am not allowed to access non-final variable in anonymous inner class.

But in Test2 class, why am I allowed to access non-final variable in anonymous inner class?

[image: TestLogging]

[image: Test2]

How is it possible to access non-final variable from anonymous inner class?

Comment: Side note: Consider using a lambda expression to minimize your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416784/thread-with-lambda-expression

Comment: Is this one of those trick questions where there is something hiding below screen view that makes everything somehow work out? Your Test2 class is quite long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between final and effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is due to the version of the JDK against which you're compiling (or the target version).

Java 8 understands **"effectively final"** variables. Where you compile with JDK 8, you do not have to explicitly declare the variable as `final` in order to reference it in the anonymous class.

In other words, the variable `s`, although not declared as final, is not being reassigned, and that makes it "effectively final" (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21473598/5761558) for more info).

Before Java 8 (and your other project - `TestLogging` - has a target version of 1.5), variables had to be explicitly declared as final

Answer (score 2):

Check maven configuration for java version
[image]